# Can PHP HTTP_HOST return value 'localhost' but REMOTE_ADDR is public ip?

Tags: php, security

I log my webapp that capture PHP $_SERVER information for security purpose.

Some of record is show **HTTP_HOST** that value is localhost but **REMOTE_ADDR** is external ip.

I have tested to access from external ip, but it show correct HTTP_HOST which is my webapp domain or server public ip address (if i use ip address)

Is this is common? if yes, how to get HTTP_HOST value to localhost from external ip?

And if no, is someone (possibly) has access to my server or try(and successfully) inject my webapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got an answer, as in PHP doc [Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> All elements of the $*SERVER array whose keys begin with 'HTTP*' come from HTTP request headers and are not to be trusted

and can be change with this method

```
curl -H "Host: notyourdomain.com" http://yoursite.com/
```